# jQuery: Cycle plugin and 100% height

Tags: jquery, css

I'm rotating images to appear in the background using the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/). However, I can't get the height to span 100%. I can get the *width* to span 100%, but I have to set the height in pixels. I attempted to set it equal to the height of the body with jQuery, but unless I specifically give it height in pixels with css, it will revert to a height of 0.

I have it set up so the following div container has a negative z-index and is located at the top of the page:

```
<div id="bg-images"> 
    <img src="images/bg-img-1.jpg" /> 
    <img src="images/bg-img-2.jpg" /> 
    <img src="images/bg-img-3.jpg" /> 
</div> 
<div id="wrapper">Page Content goes here...</div>
```

The height of the page is 1430px, but it's built on a CMS and can change. Is there some way to get my container to span 100% of the height other than `#bg-images { height:100% }` or `$("#bg-images").height() = $("body").height();`?

Answer (score 1):

As always:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```